# R Aggregate/Sum Unknown # of Columns, Based on 2 Specific Columns Matching

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe wherein I'm creating columns based on other logic to set monthly pieces of information. There are 2 standard columns called `Name` and `Category` but with additional columns such as this:

```
df>

    Name Category Oct-21 Dec-21 Nov-21
    Sam  AB       16
    Sam  AB              8
    Sam  AC              8
    Sue  AB       4      
    Sue  AB              9      
    Sue  AB                     3
    Sue  AC                     20
```

I am trying to sum/aggregate data all subsequent columns based on matching `Name` and `Category`. Because the columns to be aggregated/summed are dynamically created and I don't always know how many there will be, or their names, I want to refrain from hard-coding them. In the above example, I am attempting to create this:

```
df>

    Name Category Oct-21 Dec-21 Nov-21
    Sam  AB       16     8
    Sam  AC              8
    Sue  AB       4      9      3
    Sue  AC                     20
```

I have attempted to use `aggregate(.~ Name + Category,df,sum)` as well as `df %>% group_by(Name, Category)` but neither seems to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have `numeric` columns? Are those blanks  `""` or `NA`.  If it is `NA`, then your `aggregate` code could be `aggregate(.  ~Name + Category, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)` and the `dplyr` code `%>% summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun - the columns  `Oct-21`, `Dec-21`, etc. contain numeric values and the seemingly blank ones are `""`, not `NA`. Using your `aggregate` call i'm still seeing `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Comment: Then you need to convert the columns to numeric.  i.e. `df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)` or make those numeric columns numeric by force `df[-(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` (assuming those are factor or character) which forces the `""` and any other non-numeric elements to `NA`.  Then you may use the aggregate code above

Comment: Ahh! That did it. I thought that because I created those columns and converted the value as.numeric before placing it, I wasn't going to have datatype issues. Thank you! 